# Why is suicide inhibition considered a catalytic reaction when the catalyst is irreversibly modified because of the reaction?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, enzymes

I understand that this might be meaningless semantics, but I'm confused and would appreciate clarification.

I've always been taught that, a catalyst is, by definition, a substance that is increases the rate of a reaction but is not consumed by the reaction. Enzymes are a subset of catalysts, so all enzymes must share catalyst properties. From my understanding, suicide inhibition *irreversibly* modifies the enzyme and consumes it during its *normal* catalysis reaction.

How can an enzyme that is consumed during its normal catalysis reaction still be an enzyme? Wouldn't it make much more sense to call it a reactant?

Comment: People are people. If you give them strychnine they die, but they are still people. Enzymes are enzymes, if you poison them with inhibitors they ‘die’, but they are still enzymes. Yes this question *is* meaningless, and it hardly justifies the description of semantics. And next time you post, please read [how to ask a good question first](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and quote your sources, not your understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what the confusion stems from, but perhaps it was from the first sentence of [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_inhibition), which says:

> Suicide inhibition ... is an irreversible form of enzyme inhibition that occurs when an enzyme binds a substrate analogue and forms an irreversible complex with it through a covalent bond during the normal catalysis reaction.

This might mislead someone by using the phrase "during the normal catalysis reaction", which I suppose could be interpreted as saying the enzyme *only* catalyzes reactions involving the inhibitor.  That is very much not the case.

The normal action of the enzyme is with some other molecule, the normal substrate of the enzyme, and the catalytic reaction produces and release the product, leaving the enzyme in its original form.

In contrast to this, the inhibitor is an *analogue* of the normal substrate molecule, that is to say, a molecule which is very similar (in the target region at least) to the normal substrate molecule.  Because of the similarity, the enzyme will cause the inhibitor to undergo the same chemical reaction as the normal substrate. However, the inhibitor will thereby become active in a way which causes it to irreversibly bind to the enzyme and thus, unlike the normal substrate, will never be released.